# Cheap way to make screens for doors/windows?

Tags: home, pest-control

I live in New Zealand and buying pre-made screens for windows and doors are expensive. Looking for a cheaper alternative way to make them myself to help my pest control.

Comment: One solution that works with doors (where I live) is a bead curtain, so you can leave the door open. Insects don't like to find a way through, but it ventilates. You can make one, from ... beads and fishing line and a wood batten and two metal hooks/eyes.

Comment: @WeatherVane How long must the curtain be? Does it need to reach the floor? Do the lines need to hang close to each other to be effective? Thanx. This might make a nice answer to vote up.

Comment: @Weather Vane thank you that makes so much sense and I have seen bead curtains before now i know why...this will also help my pest control too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making screens for doors and windows is easy to do; but, there is an initial investment which may be greater than ordering a number of screens at the same time at a negotiated price.

You would go to an industrial hardware supplier or a hardware store for
**The raw materials.**

1. Window screen frame stock. It usually comes in 12' lengths of rolled or extruded aluminum or molded plastic. The shape of the frame may include a lip/flange to use for attaching the finished screen or it may be without so that it can fit into a channel.
2. Window screen cloth. This comes in rolls of variable widths and lengths.
3. Frame corners
4. Spline material to secure the screen cloth edges to the screen frame when stretched to cover the frame. Spline comes in different profiles to fit the frame stock you selected. Sometimes, depending on the frame, tape can be used in place of a spline.

**Procedure to make a Window Screen:**

1. Cut the frame stock into pieces to make the top, bottom, and sides of the window screen.
    [image: Cut the frame stock]
2. Attach the frame edges to the frame corners.
    [image: Attach the corners to the frame]
3. Lay the frame flat and cut the cloth a little larger than the frame
   [image: Lay the cloth on the frame]
4. Push the spline into the frame extrusion to secure the cloth to the frame with a hand-held roller made for this step.
   [image: Push the spline into the extrusion]
5. Trim the cloth with a utility knife. Be careful to avoid cutting into the spline.
   [image: Trim the screen cloth]
6. Repeat as necessary

An alternative will give you cheaper cost per window; but, you will need to invest in a mitre box to cut the frame stock accurately at a 45° angle to use cheaper corner brace. Mitred corners are neater than square-cut ones.
[image: Mitre box] [image: Mitred corner clip]

Good Luck
 <sub>pictures courtesy of richelieuglazingsupplies.com</sub>

Comment: Thank you for this alternative cheap way this will definitely help with my prst control and I know where i can get the material needed at a reasonable price.